# What does $ followed by a number (e.g. $1, $3) in Scheme do?

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm analyzing a code and I saw this

```
[(exp + exp) (+ $1 $3)]
```

Now I'm wondering what does this do? Does it take the first and third element of that list? Is that set on the left side even considered a list? I'm learning this language but I've been having a pretty rough time with it, so you guys have been the best help. Thanks!

Comment: The code doesn't work does it? As it stands, the code doesn't work for me, so either you're not including part of the code, or something.  I don't think `$` is an operator in scheme, but I'll wait for someone else to come along for a more confident answer.

Comment: This is just a tiny piece of the code, but I'd like to understand it bit by bit. This is a small part of a huge chunk of code so I took it out to ask.

Comment: NB It's definitely useful to provide some context though. Racket is a big language that allows libraries to modify the basic rules quite a bit, and so the exact same sequence of characters can mean radically different things depending on the context in which it occurs. Knowing that this is in the context of a parser-tools grammar expression is important.

Comment: Ok this is the code I'm trying to understand: [link](https://github.com/plt/racket/blob/master/collects/parser-tools/examples/calc.rkt) 

The code I copied is from line 70.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given your previous question, I'm guessing this is in the context of Racket's parser-tools library. From the [docs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/parser-tools/Parsers.html?q=parser-tools):

```
(grammar (non-terminal-id
      ((grammar-id ...) maybe-prec expr)
      ...)
...)
```

> Declares the grammar to be parsed. Each `grammar-id` can be a `token-id`
>   from a `group-id` named in a tokens declaration, or it can be a
>   non-terminal-id declared in the grammar declaration. The optional `prec`
>   declaration works with the `precs` declaration. The `expr` is a “semantic
>   action,” which is evaluated when the input is found to match its
>   corresponding production.
>
> Each action is Racket code that has the same scope as its parser’s
>   definition, except that the variables `$1`, ..., `$i` are bound, where i
>   is the number of grammar-ids in the corresponding production. Each `$k`
>   is bound to the result of the action for the kth grammar symbol on the
>   right of the production, if that grammar symbol is a non-terminal, or
>   the value stored in the token if the grammar symbol is a terminal.

Comment: +1...I hunted for a good bit and couldn't find this.  You're on top of your Racket game, that's for sure.